# Insert term when page is published - avoid duplicates after edits

Tags: filters, hooks, actions, terms

So i want to dynamically add terms to a custom taxonomy named after new pages when these are published. Problem I have is that when you edit the page titles, another term will be added to the taxonomy.

This snippet is from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/20068/89739), it works for inserting terms.

```
function add_page_term( $post_ID ) {
$post = get_post( $post_ID );
wp_insert_term( $post->post_title, 'mypages' );
}
add_action( 'publish_page', 'add_page_term' );
```

So far I tried to first get the post_ID and then replace it with the post_title using the [pre_insert_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_insert_term/) hook or to override the value with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) but had no success. Any ideas on this? Help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could also use [post status transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) to add new term only when post is published.

Comment: Can you give an example? I never worked with post status transitions before and I was not able to implement the hook. Also I can not update the terms when the page title changes with this method, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [post status transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) that runs only when your set conditions are met.

**Example:**

```
add_action(  'transition_post_status',  'add_awesome_terms', 10, 3 );

function add_awesome_terms( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    // only run when it's a page, new status is publish and old status isn't publish
    if ( $post->post_type == 'page' && $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status != 'publish' ) {

        // do whatever you need here, it runs only when your set conditions are met
        wp_insert_term( $post->post_title, 'mypages' );
    }
}
```

Little bonus: you already have a `$post` object and you have access to all the `$post` variables.

You might want to add your own conditions to make it *bulletproof*. It's currently ran every time new status is `publish` and old is not `publish`. It all depends how your page/post management is set up.

---

Possible post statuses:

- `new` – when there’s no previous status
- `publish` – a published post or page
- `pending` – a post pending review
- `draft` – a post in draft status
- `auto-draft` – a newly created post with no content
- `future` – a post scheduled to publish in the future
- `private` – not visible to users who are not logged in
- `inherit` – a revision or attachment
- `trash` – post is in the trash

Don't forget to use `$post` variables to your advantage, you already have it! Variables are listed [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post).

Comment: It depends.. Do you have only one term per page?

Comment: Does these terms have any front-end value for users or it's used for something else (_admin or developer stuff_)? Using `ID` would be much better, it would never need to change.